# Get the key of an array "value" for use in a function

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array defined:

```
$flatdata["body_font-family"] = "Arial";
```

I want to use that array value in a function:

```
function display_name($input) {
    showmethekeyofthearrayvalue($input); // how can I get the key name here?
}

echo display_name($flatdata["body_font-family"]);
```

So that the output is:

```
body_font-family
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
function display_key($array, $val) {
    while($array_pos = current($array)) {
        if($array_pos == $val) {
            return key($array);
        }
    }
}

echo display_key($flatdata, $flatdata["body_font-family"]);
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  key() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Comment: Same problem as before.

Comment: Works perfect now, didn't think there would be a solution. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) I accidently returned `key($val)` instead of `key($array)` firstly

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
key($arr);
```

This will return the key name

From the [manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

> key() returns the index element of the current array position.

Or you may try to use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$arr = array ('key1' => 'a', 'key2' => 'b', );
$key = array_search ('a', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `displaykey` is supposed to be `display_name` in your example.

If so, you won't be able to return the key by passing in an array element such as `$flatdata["body_font-family"]` because in this case you're only passing in a specific string i.e. `Arial`, so the function doesn't have any info about the key.

Comment: You're probably correct. I thought there was some kind of PHP function I didn't know, but alas.

Comment: @Taapo another way to think of it is that the call in your example is the equivalent of `display_name('Arial')`